# Twisted producer to many clients with buffer

Tags: python, twisted

I am using twisted to distribute some information to several clients.

I have a consumer (implements `IConsumer`) with the `write` method overridden to write to all connected consumer clients.

I have a data source implemented as a generator.

Here is my main function

```
factory = TelemetryFactory()
one2many = ConsumerToManyClientConsumers()
# writes from the datalines generator to one2many
telem = TelemetryProducer(one2many, datalines)
factory.setSource(one2many)
reactor.listenTCP(1234, factory)
reactor.run()
```

How do I run the generator (or the TelemetryProducer) so that the it always runs no matter how many clients there are (0-10)?

**Edit:** Using reactor.callInThread(fn) seems to give the desired behaviour, except that CTRL+C doesn't properly exit the program. After CTRL+C, all connections are refused, but control is not yielded back to the shell.

Comment: What generator?  What `fn`?  Please see http://sscce.org/

Comment: The generator is any generator. It produces data from some source. The  function runs the generator and writes data into the one2many consumer, which in turn writes to connected clients. The code is not really relevant to the question though, perhaps including it was a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`twisted.internet.task.cooperate`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.task.cooperate.html).